# Create a view with two entity class having same structure

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I had two entiy class having same structure (temp entity and permanent entity) I want to create a view so that it can query from both the table in case of if I apply logic for search or advance search etc.

I am thinking about trying " select * from temp union select * from permanent " using @Immutable annotations